What does "Watch me run a 50-yard dash with my legs cut off" quote mean?
Sidney snatches the phone from his female assistant Sally, with Joe Robard on the
other end of the call.

Sidney (to Sally): Watch me run a 50-yard dash with my legs cut off.

Sidney then proceeds to talk on the phone:

Sidney: Sidney: Hey, Joe. Joe, it's Sidney. How do you like this?

The “50-yard dash” is a short sprint race, and doing it “with my legs cut off”
is obviously impossible.
What does "Watch me run a 50-yard dash with my legs cut off" quote mean?

Not my DV, but seems quite obvious though: "[...] and doing it “with my legs cut off” is obviously impossible. What does it mean? that he's going to succeed doing something that's nearly impossible?

Sidney is planning to lie to his client about why he hasn't got his promised write-up in the Hunsecker Column about his new nightclub, despite having paid Sid over three hundred dollars. Sidney doesn't have any evidence to back up his tall tale and his lie is frankly enormous, telling Joe that it is actually a good thing that he has not seen the story yet(!) because it will be even more satisfying to get the whole column(!!) devoted to his club, not just a mention.
In this context, he is trying to bamboozle somebody who is already extremely dubious about the money he has given to him, for no obvious return. Sydney is telling his secretary to watch (and marvel) as he achieves a feat of the near impossible.
